# Error in Virtual box with RHEL 6

Tags: redhat, virtualbox, kernel, rhel6

While using Virtual Box in RHEL 6 at the time of starting virtual OS getting following error. Help me to resolve this.[image]

Virtual Box version VirtualBox-4.1-4.1.8_75467_rhel6-1.i686

Operating System RHEL 6.1

Comment: Please take a few moments to read the error message, as it includes the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you trued to run

```
 /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

as the message told you?

Comment: can you please explain about problem. i could not understand it clearly. that's why

Comment: VirtualBox uses kernel modules what has to compiled for the actual system and loaded by an init script. It seem it isn't done yet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the kernel header is not installed. So, Install the kernel headers  and reinstall the virtualbox .This will fix the problem.